# namespace直下の関数でinlineかstaticがないとビルドエラーになるのはなぜですか

Tags: c++

Visual C++ 2019で作成しています。
以下のようにnamespace直下においた関数では、inlineとstaticの少なくともいずれか一つがないと、ビルドに失敗します。なぜでしょうか。

・Sample10.cpp

```cpp
#include "ABC.cpp"
int main()
{
    nspace::show_static_inline();
    nspace::show_static();
    nspace::show_inline();
    return 0;
}
```

・ABC.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
namespace nspace
{
    inline static void show_static_inline() {
        std::cout << "show_static_inline" << std::endl;
    }

    /*inline*/ static void show_static() {
        std::cout << "show_static" << std::endl;
    }

    inline /*static*/ void show_inline() {
        std::cout << "show_inline" << std::endl;
    }

    
    //↓ビルドでエラー。
    /*inline static*/ void show() {
        std::cout << "show" << std::endl;
    }   
    /* エラー内容
    1>Sample10.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl nspace::show(void)" (?show@nspace@@YAXXZ) は既に ABC.obj で定義されています。
    1>C:\Users\○○○○\source\repos\Sample10\Debug\Sample10.exe : fatal error LNK1169: 1 つ以上の複数回定義されているシンボルが見つかりました。
    */
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

短い答え：ほとんどすべてのケースで

```
#include "hoge.cpp"
```

と書くのは誤りです。

---

長い答え：どのようにコンパイルし、どのように **リンク** しているかで話は違ってきますが

```
cl Sample10.cpp ABC.cpp
```

のように両方のファイルをコンパイル・リンクしていれば当然の結果です。現に、ウチでは

```
cl Sample10.cpp
g++ Sample10.cpp
```

でどちらもコンパイル・リンク・実行に成功しています。多分実行結果も期待通りでしょう。

`#include` は単にそのファイルの内容をその場所に展開するだけですので `Sample10.cpp` 中に `#include "ABC.cpp"` と記載してしまうと、そこに `ABC.cpp` の内容がそのまま展開されます。 `cl Sample10.cpp ABC.cpp` とすると結果的に `ABC.cpp` の内容は２回コンパイルされるので、リンク時に重複エラーになります。 `inline` があるとインライン展開されて重複しない `static` があると重複を認める、のでどちらもリンクエラーにならないわけです。

ではどう直すかですが、この例の場合 `ABC.cpp` でなくて `ABC.h` (あるいは `ABC.hpp` でも) にして、コンパイル対象から外すのが良いでしょう。統合開発環境は `cpp` ファイルを自動的にコンパイル対象にするためです。